# How to iterate a nesting object which is under the payload object from Firebase database in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, firebase

[NoSQL database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHSxP.gif)

```
<input #title="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="product.payload.val().title" name="title" required id="title" type="text" class="form-control">
```

Comment: Post the data retrieving code too.

Comment: @ask.drupal : Please go through stack overflow guideline for asking question before posting any question. I am not able to see completed code. Please update you question with proper description.

Comment: using 2 ways binding with this: [(ngModel)]="product.payload.val().title", but got ERROR : Cannot read property 'title' of undefined.
Please see "NoSQL database" above to show you the database structure.
Many thanks.

Comment: i saw that, you need to post the code from component.ts where you getting the data from database.

Comment: this is the structure in json format : 
```{ "payload": { "category": "africa", "imageUrl": "image 01", "price": 12, "title": "test04" }, "type": "value", "prevKey": null, "key": "-KzWO7MPXevJSgLEdKoT" }```

if the input binding this --> ``` [(ngModel)]="product.type``` , it will get ```value```.
but I have no idea how to get the value of [object, object].